# How to send photo of my baseball for whose auto

Tags: discussion

I see someone has posted a photo of an autographed baseball wondering whose it was. I also purchaseed an autographed baseball in the mid 90's and would like to send you a photo but do not know how.

Comment: Welcome to Sports.SE.  Just above the question editing box where you typed the question, there is a button that looks like a framed picture.  Click that to add a picture to your question. Go ahead and [ask a new question](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and post your photo to it.

Comment: [Edit your Question](http://i.imgur.com/DoScmE7.gif)

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴠʏ going above and beyond. nice, quick tutorial.

Comment: @ᴍᴀsᴛᴇʀᴍɪɴᴅ_ᴇᴅ ,Oh thank you :), but it looks like the OP didn't came back after my comment.